# Setting VBUS_MIN and ISNK_COARSE/FINE on an Infineon CY4535

Tags: schematics, voltage-divider, datasheet, documentation

I am using the [Infineon CY4535 EZ-PD evaluation kit](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/evaluation-boards/cy4535/?redirId=199217) to power a 5V, 3A device from a USB-C source. I am having trouble reconciling schematics and tables given in the documentation ([PDF link here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-CY4535_BCR_LITE-UserManual-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c80f4d32901811e3527f94e99)) that appear contradictory.

The evaluation kit uses a couple of voltage divider networks to set the min/max output voltages and current. This schematic from the linked documentation shows the default minimum voltage (VBUS_MIN) setting of 5.0v from the factory:

[image]

And this table describes how to alter the minimum voltage:
[image]

There is also some text that provides an example that is different from the default:

> For example, if the divider on VBUS_MIN is set to 9 V (i.e. R14 = 5 kΩ pull-up, R13 = 1 kΩ pull-down) and...

So the text example clearly uses the second row from the table and is easily understood. But why is there a "0" in the table for R13 on the 5v setting but a 10kOhm resistor in the schematic? A multimeter confirms that there is indeed a 10kOhm resistor in R13 from the factory, and R14 is not populated. I would expect "0" to mean that the pads should be shorted together.

---

I found a similar situation for the ISNK_COARSE and ISNK_FINE networks. The factory defaults are given in these schematics:

[image]

But for a current setting of 900mA, R17 and R20 in the schematic don't seem to match the tables in the device manual:

[image]

In Table 4, "0" for R17 apparently means 10kOhm again, while in Table 5, "0" for R20 seems to mean a 5kOhm resistor.

---

Am I misunderstanding this documentation or is there an error? I want to confirm that VBUS_MIN is 5v and set the operating current to 3A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the resistor values mentioned in tables 3, 4, and 5 are right. 0Ohm (short) to GND or VDDD would be sufficient.
However 5kOhm or 10kOhm resistors are often used for safety considerations when connecting a GPIO directly to the VDDD rail or the GND.

This resistor limits the current flowing in/out of the GPIO in case the GPIOs are wrongly configured. Since the other resistor in either of the configurations is DNP, it is recommended to use these resistors. It will not affect the voltage divider values.

**Disclosure:** I work as a support engineer with Infineon at the time of writing.